# ContentControl not showing up without specifying width/height

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol

I am using [CefSharp](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp) in my WPF project. I'm adding the `CefSharp.Wpf.WebView` class to my MainWindow.xaml like so:

```
_webView = new WebView(url, _settings);
```

My XAML layout looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFContainer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test Project" Height="400" Width="930" Initialized="OnWindowInit" StateChanged="OnWindowStateChanged" Closing="OnWindowClose">
  <DockPanel Name="MainDockPanel" Height="400" Width="930">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ShowGridLines="True" Name="mainGrid" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="col1" Width="600" />
            <ColumnDefinition Name="col2" Width="330"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

If I remove the `Grid` and add the `webView` to the `DockPanel` directly, it shows up just fine. But if I try to add the `webView` to `col1` in the `Grid`, it doesn't display. It will display in the grid column if I specify a Width/Height, but `HorizontalAlignment.Stretch` doesnt work and I need 100% width and height!

My code for adding the `webView` to the Grid which doesn't work:

```
mainGrid.Children.Add(_webView);
Grid.SetColumn(_webView, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Children property is populated in InitializeComponent. If you are adding children to the grid after it has been initialize, there is no property changed event for adding to the Children collection, as it is not an ObservableCollection. If you were to create a new collection I believe it would work programmatically, but that can be avoided by defining your webview in xaml (provided it has a paramaterless constructor). Then OnLoaded you can inject url and settings.

Comment: Then how come if I set a width and height it shows up? And is there another way to set width = 100% etc?

Comment: this link explains wpf layout in more detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx. Typically custom controls are written to consume as much space as they need or all the space they are given in the measure pass. It is the job of the panel (in this case a grid) to limit the amount of space it gives to it's children, and to arrange them in relation to itself.